# When HI reacts with H2SO4, why is the sulphate ion reduced to hydrogen sulphide instead of sulfur dioxide?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, redox, oxidation-state

When $\ce{HI}$ reacts with $\ce{H2SO4}$, it can be represented by the following chemical equation:

$$\ce{8HI + H2SO4 -> 4I2 + H2S + 4H2O}$$

However, when $\ce{HBr}$ reacts with $\ce{H2SO4}$, the sulphate ion is reduced to sulphur dioxide instead:

$$\ce{2HBr + H2SO4 -> Br2 + SO2 + 2H2O}$$

Could anyone account for the difference here? Is there any more cases where the sulphate ion is reduced to $\ce{H2S}$ instead of $\ce{SO2}$?

Comment: Chem+Math Expression formatting reference:
 [MathJax Basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation) / [Chem+Math expressions/formulas/equations](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here) / [Upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized) / [Math SE Mathjax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)
// MathJax is preferred not to be used in CH SE Q titles.

Comment: Apparently iodide ion is a better reducing agent. Any table of EMF potentials that includes nonmetal reactions will tell you that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The book intitled Qualitative Analysis emitted by F. P. Treadwell in $1924$ mentions in the chapter Iodine (p. 323) that the reaction depends on the relative amount of $\ce{H2SO4}$. In the presence of a great excess of $\ce{H2SO4}$, its reaction on $\ce{HI}$ or iodides produces $\ce{SO2}$ apart from $\ce{I2}$. In the presence of an excess of iodides, the reaction produces $\ce{H2S}$ as mentioned by Jelly Qwerty.

Comment: Is there any explanation to this? Or is it purely empirical

Comment: If an explanation is to be found about this phenomena, it may be said that the first reaction between $\ce{H2SO4}$ and $\ce{HI}$ (or $\ce{KI}$) reduces sulfur from +$6$ to +$4$. The equation is  $$\ce{H2SO4 + 2 HI -> SO2 + I2 + 2 H2O}$$ Then, in case of an excess of $\ce{HI}$, the Sulfur is further reduced from +$4$ to -$2$ according to the following equatoion : $$\ce{SO2  + 6 HI  ->  H2S  + 3 I2  +  2 H2O}$$

Answer (score 1):

As @Oscar said, hydrogen iodide (or iodide ion) is much stronger reducing agent than hydrogen bromide (or bromide ion). So the sulfuric acid reduce through a rather complicated pathway than just ending up with $\ce{SO2}$. The reduction pathway is somewhat like this:

$$\ce{H2SO4 -> SO2 -> S -> H2S}$$

Sulfurous acid is an intermediate product in the reaction which takes part in the transient reactions forming sulfur, hence driving the reduction reaction forward.
$$\ce{SO2 (or H2SO3) + 2H2S -> 3S + 2H2O}$$

...and yes, if one of the reagent is a very strong reducing agent, you can end up with hydrogen sulfide instead of sulfur dioxide.

You can read the following articles:

1. https://www.chemguide.co.uk/inorganic/group7/halideions.html
2. *Sulphuric Acid and Hydriodic Acid*, Florence Bush, The Journal of Physical Chemistry **1929** 33 (4), 613-620, DOI: [10.1021/j150298a010](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/j150298a010)